# Why do I need this CString type cast?

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I have moved my strings to resources and luckily I have `LPCTSTR` operator to instantiate strings conveniently like:

```
CString str( (LPCTSTR) IDS_MY_STRING);
```

Now I want to do similar type casting with `MessageBox()` so it loads the strings from resources as well so I go about like this:

```
MessageBox( hWnd, (LPCTSTR) IDS_MY_STRING , _T("Error"), MB_RETRYCANCEL);
```

But this doesn't work, it compiles but crashes at run time. Now the following does work:

```
MessageBox( hWnd, (CString) (LPCTSTR) IDS_MY_STRING , _T("Error"), MB_RETRYCANCEL);
```

My question is that `MessageBox()` takes `LPCTSTR` as 2nd parameter anyways so why do we have to typecast additionally from `LPCTSTR` to `CString` to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have explained the details of type casts, etc.

Moreover, to simplify your code, you may want to `#define` a convenient macro like this:

```
#define _S(id) (CString(LPCTSTR(id)))
```

and then use it with `MessageBox` (or for other `LPCTSTR` parameters as well):

```
MessageBox( hWnd, _S(IDS_MY_STRING), _S(IDS_TITLE), MB_RETRYCANCEL );
```

Answer (score 5):

The real question (or at least the interesting part of the answer) is less about how the second fails, and more about how the first works.

The first works because `CString`'s constructor that takes an `LPCTSTR` actually looks at the value to figure out whether it's really a pointer to a string, or the identifier of a string resource. In the latter case, it automatically loads the string resource and creates a `CString` with the same content. IOW, you're getting an implicit conversion from string identifier to `CString`.

`CString` also supports an implicit conversion to `LPCTSTR`/`LPCSTR`/`LPCWSTR`.

C++, however, will only do *one* user-defined implicit conversion to get from whatever type is passed to whatever type is needed for an expression. In this case, to get from a string ID to a `LPCTSTR`, you'd need two -- one from string ID to `CString`, and another from `CString` to `LPCTSTR`. The compiler won't do that for you automatically.

Therefore, to get from a string ID to an `LPCTSTR`, you need to explicitly convert from string ID to `CString`, which uses `CString`'s constructor that takes an `LPCTSTR`. Therefore, you cast your string ID to `LPCTSTR`, and from that to `CString`, which creates a `CString`. Then the compiler will automatically convert from `CString` to a (real) `LPCTSTR` for you.

Comment: Your last para is a little confusing. I think you want to say is we still need one conversion which is from `string ID` to `CString`. Than CString has implicit conversion to LPCTSTR. By typcasting `(CString) (LPCTSTR)`we are doing one conversion from ID to CString.

Comment: Would not it be more readable to write `CString((LPCTSTR)IDS_MY_STRING)` instead of two explicit casts?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Yes, I'd probably do it that way anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your `IDS_MY_STRING` isn't really a pointer to a string. It's an integer. (If it were a string pointer, you'd never need the `LPCTSTR` cast in the first place.) `CString` knows how to load resource strings from integral resource IDs.

`MessageBox` doesn't; it requires a real character pointer, which `CString` provides implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox` does not have an overload taking a resource ID but you can use `AfxMessageBox` instead.